# Set selection dropdown value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dropdown, html-select

I'm trying to set a value for a selection dropdown using javascript. Please see the pictures below. When I manually change the value of the dropdown list (by clicking), the timeline changes in accordance to the new value.

selection dropdown

[image]

timeline

[image]

When I do the following with javascript:
myDropdown.selectedIndex = 4;
The value is changed in the dropdown, but it doesn't update on the timeline. Is there any way to trigger this update?

Comment: It depends on what event the logic is waiting for.  If it is a change event then you could create an event and dispatch it on the select object after you have changed it.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: If you have an onchange="updateTimeline()" then do `myDropdown.selectedIndex = 4; myDropdown.onchange()` or `myDropdown.selectedIndex = 4; updateTimeline()`

Comment: I've tried using myDropdown.onchange() but nothing happens. I haven't yet found the onchange method - it's not in the select class itself. I guess I need to look through the javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going through a huge javascript file.
What eventually worked was to call the dropdown change function with: $(".timeslotdrop").change();